# How to assign value to a Lazy Loading object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

I am new on lazy loading, but I want to be able to fill my lazy loading objects after it was created too. Is it possible?

I am getting this error when I want to define a "Lazy loading list" as a normal list I created:

Cannot implicitly convert type: 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Lazy>'

Here is the code:

```
List<Currency> currencyOfMids = new List<Currency>();
 obj.Merchant.CurrencyOfMids = currencyOfMids;
```

I tried identifying my list as a Lazy list too, but this time I can't fill it with "Add" command:

```
 foreach (ListItem currencyItem in selectedCurrencies)
                currencyOfMids.Add(new Currency() { Code = currencyItem.Text, Id = int.Parse(currencyItem.Value) });
```

'Lazy>' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'Lazy>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Suggest you go look at some examples. Your code should have a `Lazy<List<Currency>>` declaration in it somewhere.

Comment: Yes it has that declaration and I want to keep it. Just want to know if it's possible to assign values to a Lazy loading object?

Comment: Is obj.Merchant.CurrencyOfMids of the type Lazy<List<Currency>> and you are trying to assign to it?

Comment: @DevNoob Exactly, yes. Is it possible?

Comment: Not exactly.  See my answer below.  Hopefully that is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `Lazy<T>.Value` property.  The Value property is how you access the T object (in your case, a `List<Currency>`.  The Value is automatically initialized the first time that you access it (which is what makes it lazy).  You can't assign to value, but you can loop through `currencyOfMids` and add each value to `obj.Merchant.CurrencyOfMids.Value`.

```
foreach (ListItem currencyItem in selectedCurrencies)
            currencyOfMids.Value.Add(new Currency() { Code = currencyItem.Text, Id = int.Parse(currencyItem.Value) });
```

Comment: You are right, that looks like the solution, let me try when I get a chance.

Comment: There would be no point assigning a `List<Currency>` lazily and then completing it 'manually' like this. It would be better to simply have an empty `List<Currency>` than a `Lazy<List<Currency>>` that generates an empty list on first access. @NecatiHakanErdogan

Answer (score 1):

You can assign to a `Lazy<T>`, passing it the code that will create the list lazily when needed:

```
obj.Merchant.currencyOfMids = new Lazy<List<Currency>>(
   () => ... code to generate currencies ...
);
```

Now when you want the list you access `currencyofMids.Value` and if it hasn't already been generated it will generate it.